# Simplification of a context free grammar

Tags: theory, context-free-grammar, computation

Given the context-free grammar `G = ( {S, A, B, C} , {0, 1} , P , S)`, where the    set of productions `P` is:

```
S → 0A0 | 1B1 | BB
A → C
B → S | A
C → S | λ
```

I am supposed to remove the useless symbols.

My questions is should I consider the empty string λ a terminal here while applying the algorithm where I create a new set `V'` containing symbols resulting in direct derivations then adding to `V'` symbols that produce a combination of terminals and variables in `V'`.
Any guidance is appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

λ is not a terminal, and you should not make it one. It is, however, a (trivial) "combination of terminals and non-terminals".